# Shading a heart

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, tikz-fadings

I want to draw and fill the below heart with TikZ package.
I use the shading option for the whole heart or two semi-heart curve.
It seem the heart divided!
Please help me correct the suitable shading option.
Thank you in advance!
My code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \def\cur{(0,-2.7)..controls (-1.85,-1.45) and (-1.8,-0.52)..(-1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (-1.52,0.63) and (-0.37,0.74)..(0,0)
 ..controls (0.37,0.74) and (1.52,0.63)..(1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (1.8,-0.52) and  (1.85,-1.45).. cycle};
\path[shading=ball,ball color=red] \cur;

 \def\curh{(0,-2.7)..controls (-1.85,-1.45) and (-1.8,-0.52)..(-1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (-1.52,0.63) and (-0.37,0.74)..(0,0)};

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\path[shading=ball,ball color=red] \curh;
\path[shading=ball,ball color=red,xscale=-1] \curh;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version after suguestions. Thank you very much for all help!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{heart}{\pgfpoint{-0.45cm}{0.35cm}}%
{%
  color(0cm)=(white!50!red);
  color(0.25cm)=(red!90!black);
  color(0.75cm)=(red!70!black);
  color(1.5cm)=(red!60!black)
}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{heart2}{\pgfpoint{0.45cm}{0.35cm}}%
{%
  color(0cm)=(white!50!red);
  color(0.25cm)=(red!90!black);
  color(0.75cm)=(red!70!black);
  color(1.5cm)=(red!60!black)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetblendmode{lighten}
\def\cur{(0,-2.7)..controls (-1.85,-1.45) and (-1.8,-0.52)..(-1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (-1.52,0.63) and (-0.37,0.74)..(0,0)
 ..controls (0.37,0.74) and (1.52,0.63)..(1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (1.8,-0.52) and  (1.85,-1.45).. cycle};
\draw[line width=2pt,red!60!black]  \cur;
\path[shading=heart] \cur;
\path[shading=heart2] \cur;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\cur{(0,-2.7)..controls (-1.85,-1.45) and (-1.8,-0.52)..(-1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (-1.52,0.63) and (-0.37,0.74)..(0,0)
 ..controls (0.37,0.74) and (1.52,0.63)..(1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (1.8,-0.52) and  (1.85,-1.45).. cycle};
\clip \cur;
\fill[top color=white, bottom color=red!80!black, middle color=red!75!black] (-2,-0.8) rectangle (2,0.5); 
\fill[red!75!black, yshift=-0.5cm] \cur;
\fill[red!75!black, outer color=red!75!black, inner color=orange] (0,-1) circle[radius=0.8];
\fill[red!75!black, outer color=red!75!black, inner color=orange] (-1.6,-1.5) circle[radius=0.8];
\fill[red!75!black, outer color=red!75!black, inner color=white] (1.8,-1.5) circle[radius=1];
\draw[red!75!black, line width=8pt] \cur;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red and orange shaded hearth]

Comment: What a beautifull heart. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a starting point. It needs some adjustments.

I changed your paths for arcs and circles, this way I know the centers. Then, the key here is to make a couple of shadings. It needs some more shadings to look like the original picture, as I said: a starting point.

**Edit:** Slightly better (imho) adding `lighten` blend mode.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\outerheart}
  {(0,0) arc (30:210:1) to [out=-60,in=150] (0,-2.75) to [out=30,in=240] (-30:2) arc (-30:150:1)}
\newcommand{\innerheart}
  {(210:0.1) arc (30:210:0.9)  to [out=-60,in=150] (0,-2.65) to [out=30,in=240]
   (-30:1.9) arc (-30:150:0.9) to [out=240,in=300] cycle}
   
\pgfdeclareradialshading{heart}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
{%
  color(0cm)=(yellow!50!red);
  color(0.3cm)=(red!90!black);
  color(0.6cm)=(red!70!black);
  color(2cm)=(red!60!black)
}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{shine}{2cm}%
{%
  color(0cm)=(yellow!50!red);
  color(1.6cm)=(red!70!black);
  color(2cm)=(white)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetblendmode{lighten}
\begin{scope}
  \clip\outerheart;
  \fill[shading=heart] (0,-1) circle (2);
\end{scope}
\foreach\i in {210,330}
{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(\i:1)}]
    \clip (150:0.9) arc (150:30:0.9) to [out=140,in=40] cycle;
    \fill[shading=shine] (0,0) circle (0.9);
  \end{scope}
}
\fill[red!80!black,even odd rule]\outerheart\innerheart;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: The \pgfdeclareradialshading{heart} command is very usefull.
The code is on the edited post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine both paths in one. For example like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\curh{(0,-2.7)..controls (-1.85,-1.45) and (-1.8,-0.52)..(-1.7,-0.13)
 ..controls (-1.52,0.63) and (-0.37,0.74)..(0,0)};

\path[shading=ball,ball color=red] \curh [xscale=-1] \curh;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show how half a heart can be used to make a full heart. The problem with only using half a path is that to `\draw` it and to make it a closed path for `\fill`, you need not just to reflect the path but also to reverse the stroke. `spath3` to the rescue:

```tex
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{spath3}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\curh{(0,-2.7)..controls (-1.85,-1.45) and (-1.8,-0.52)..(-1.7,-0.13)
     ..controls (-1.52,0.63) and (-0.37,0.74)..(0,0)};
    \path[spath/save=apath] \curh;
    \filldraw[
      green,
      draw=black,
      ultra thick,
      spath/use=apath
    ] [spath/transform={apath}{xscale=-1}, spath/use={apath, reverse, move, weld}] -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Green hearth]